# What is upgraded version (most similar) of JAVA SE 6 programmer exam?

Tags: java, oracle, certificate

I couldn't see JAVA SE 6 exam anymore [here](https://education.oracle.com/java/java-se/product_267?certPage=true). I want to know that which exam has replaced this exam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upgrade to Java SE 11 (1Z0-817):

**Link:**

https://education.oracle.com/upgrade-ocp-java-6-7-8-to-java-se-11-developer/pexam_1Z0-817